# How to control ion-backdrop in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic3

I have search in the API docs and Components list and I have not found any info regarding how to use the `ion-backdrop` component.

If I append it into a component of my own it gets showed but the `opacity` is set at `0.1` and I am not sure if I have to put some kind of manual timeout to change it or if there is better way to control it using the component itself.

Does somebody knows where can I find the docs or how to show it in a correct way?

Comment: There was an ionic 1 app here https://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/azrgOr